# How would writing methods for a non-generic stack class work?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, stack

I'm a little confused on how classes, constructors, and stacks work. I'm trying to create an array with a default size of 5. Then, I have to set the array size by using a constructor. Then, I have to write methods to push and pop values in the array. This is what I have so far

```
public class createStack{

    double [] array = new double[5];

    private int top = 0;

    public createStack(double[] array){

        this.array = array;

    }
    public void push(double[] array){
        if(top >= array.length){
            System.out.println("Stack is full");

        }

        top++;

    }
}
```

Am I doing this correctly? Also, how would I write methods for push and pop? I understand how the methods work, but I'm really confused on where to go with them.

Comment: The question is not specific enough. Are you having a problem? If the code works as intended, you're doing it correctly.

Comment: @Gendarme I'm not getting any errors, but I wasn't sure if my constructor for setting the array size after giving it a default value of 5 was correct. And like I said, I wasn't sure on how to write methods for pushing and popping a value

Comment: Normally you'd have two constructors. One parameterless one that sets it to a default array, and one where you can specify the array yourself (or perhaps specify the length).

Comment: @Gendarme I now have the first parameterless constructor that sets the array to a default value of 5. I'm trying to write the second constructor that sets the size, but I have no idea what to use inside of it. I tried this.array = array, but that doesn't work

Comment: `public createStack(int size) { this.array = new double[size]; }`

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems here:

- Classes are named with noun phrases, not verb phrases.
- Class names conventionally begin with a capital letter. E.g., `DoubleStack` not `createStack`.
- It doesn't make sense to have an initializer for the field but also assign the field based on a value passed to the constructor. The value passed to the constructor is always going to supersede the initializer.
- The semantics of `top` are unclear. Does it point to the current top of the stack, or the next slot that will be used? It *sounds* like the former, but since the stack starts out empty, `top = 0` can't point to the current top, so it *appears* to be the latter.
- It doesn't make any sense for `push` to take an array as a parameter. It should take the single `double` value to push onto the stack.
- Also, `push` doesn't do anything with the backing array in the field, it only looks at the array that was passed to it.

Here's an example of something more like I would expect to see:

```
public class DoubleStack {
    private double[] array;
    private int top = -1; // top points to the current top of the stack, if any

    public DoubleStack() {
        array = new double[5];
        // note: this could be done with an initializer and this constructor could be omitted
    }

    public void push(double value) {
        if (top >= array.length - 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Stack Overflow");
        }
        ++top;
        array[top] = value;
        // note: the previous two lines could be combined; keeping it simple
    }

    public double pop() {
        if (top < 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack Empty");
        }
        double value = array[top];
        --top;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Possible changes would be to have a constructor that took a size as a parameter and created an array of the desired size instead of the default of 5; or using an `ArrayList<Double>` as a backing store for the stack so that the size would not be fixed.

Comment: This all makes perfect sense. The code works, and I used test code in main, but when it runs the only thing that prints out is com.company.StackExample@4554617c, 5 times, which I'm guess is the memory address instead of the actual numbers I'm pushing to the stack?

Comment: @clueless_b What are you printing?

Comment: I'm trying to print out the numbers in the stack as they're pushed, and then print them as they're popped

Comment: That looks like what you'd get if you printed an instance of `StackExample` (and it didn't have a `toString()` method, not if you printed the numbers. Try `System.out.println(stack.pop());`